# When I flag a question as duplicate, does it make sense to edit the "possible duplicate" comment?

Tags: support, review-queues, duplicate-questions

I flagged one question A (from the triage queue) as duplicate of B. This automatically added a comment in A saying "possible duplicate of B".

However, on closer inspection I noticed that B was also a duplicate itself of C. So I manually edited the automatic comment in A to say "possible duplicate o C" instead.

Does that make sense? Will it be helpful or only create more confusion when the question is evaluated in the close queue?

References:

**A**) [What is the backslash in `new \SendGrid(…` within PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41435431/what-is-the-backslash-in-new-sendgrid-within-php) (triage question)
**B**) [Backslash in PHP — what does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788400/backslash-in-php-what-does-it-mean) (faux original; also flagged as duplicate)
**C**) [Backslash syntax when creating objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075521/backslash-syntax-when-creating-objects) (original; hopefully :)

Comment: In some cases I'd say no. And in some cases I'd say yes. In this case, I'd say no. Question B has a fine answer providing a link to the official documentation. And is the if someone really wants to see Question C they can simply click the link.

Comment: Still, isn't B a duplicate nevertheless? Shouldn't it be marked as so despite of its quality? I believe flagging it as duplicate won't cause it to be removed, just add a note clearly stating that it's duplicate.

Comment: I have a pretty good day when I can amend the text "... and 1,000 others like this". I only save this for blindingly obvious superdupes, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm only going to respond to your title:

> When I flag a question as duplicate, does it make sense to edit the “possible duplicate” comment?

Only if your edit is relevant for the duration of the close-vote. Once closed, your comment will be automatically deleted, and there's nothing you can do about it.

See also [Don't delete comments with link to duplicate if they are modified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141414/dont-delete-comments-with-link-to-duplicate-if-they-are-modified).

Comment: This is a huge caveat, and why I stopped editing these comments and typically opt to just add a new comment. Otherwise you never know if the OP even saw your extra information before it was deleted.

Answer (score 10):

There is nothing wrong with editing the "possible duplicate" comment. In fact, I do this frequently, and I've never seen it cause confusion.

Most of the time, I edit it to include links to *additional* relevant/duplicate questions. These are useful to others because they not only appear in the comment, but they also appear in the "Linked" questions section in the sidebar. They even *continue* to be displayed in the "Linked" sidebar after the "possible duplicate" comment is deleted (upon successful closure of the question). Another possible benefit is that someone else who votes to close might choose one of the other duplicates. Then, the question would be closed with multiple duplicate targets, making it even easier to get at the relevant information. (Although merging would probably be a better choice, that's a moderator-only privilege, and doesn't get done *nearly* as often as it should.)

Here, though, it sounds like you've changed your mind about which question would be a better duplicate target. That's perfectly fine, too, and if you no longer think that "B" was a reasonable choice, you can edit the comment to replace it with "C". This way, future close voters would at least be presented with both options, and therefore have to make a choice of their own. Hopefully, they would choose the best option. I don't think this would lead to any confusion. If they read your comment, it'll be obvious which duplicate you are proposing. If they don't read your comment, well, they'll just pile on for the original question that you picked, which isn't great, but there isn't much you can do about that, and at least the question will be closed.

Comment: _"if you no longer think that "B" was a reasonable choice, you can edit the comment to replace it with "C". This way, future close voters would at least be presented with both options"_ - does it really work like that?

Comment: Of course it does. The comment is right there in front of their face. :-) Also, I think that the auto-suggestion function of the super-duper-close-voter-wizard draws from questions linked in comments, but I could be wrong about that.

Comment: Oh yeah obviously I meant the latter (_"auto-suggestion function of the super-duper-close-voter-wizard"_), I'm not sure about whether that works either.